# AngularJS and Restangular, trying to convert update method to API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach, restangular, data-manipulation

I'm trying to convert my basic crud operations into an API that multiple components of my application can use.

I have successfully converted all methods, except the update one because it calls for each property on the object to be declared before the put request can be executed.

**controller**

```
$scope.update = function(testimonial, id) {
    var data = {
        name: testimonial.name,
        message: testimonial.message
    };
    dataService.update(uri, data, $scope.id).then(function(response) {
        console.log('Successfully updated!');
    }, 
    function(error) {
        console.log('Error updating.');
    });
}
```

**dataService**

```
dataService.update = function(uri, data, id) {
    var rest = Restangular.one(uri, id);

    angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
        // needs to be in the format below
        // rest.key = data.key
    });

    // needs to output something like this, depending on what the data is passed
    // rest.name = data.name;
    // rest.message = data.message;

    return rest.put();
}
```

I tried to describe the problem in the codes comments, but to reiterate I cannot figure out how to generate something like `rest.name = data.name;` without specifying the name property because the update function shouldn't need to know the object properties.

Here is what the update method looked like before I started trying to make it usable by any of my components (this works)

```
Testimonial.update = function(testimonial, id) {
    var rest = Restangular.one('testimonials', id);
    rest.name = testimonial.name;
    rest.message = testimonial.message;
    return rest.put();
}
```

How can I recreate this without any specific properties parameters hard-coded in?

Also, my project has included lo-dash, if that helps, I don't know where to start with this problem. Thanks a ton for any advice!

Comment: Try like angular.extend(rest,testimonial)

Comment: thanks @Whisher I hadn't ever used `angular.extend`, it worked perfectly, if you write that in an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like

```
angular.extend(rest,testimonial)
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend